# issues with protobuf in the sagemaker

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, amazon-sagemaker, factorization

I m trying to do the factorization machine algorithm in the sagemaker but it's giving me ValueError

its originally for a sparse matrix but my data isn't so I changed it too dense

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
Here is the code:


train_key      = 'train.protobuf'
train_prefix   = '{}/{}/'.format(prefix, 'train')
test_key       = 'test.protobuf'
test_prefix    = '{}/{}/'.format(prefix, 'test')
output_prefix  = '{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix)
def writeDatasetToProtobuf(X, y, bucket, prefix, key):
    import io,boto3
    import sagemaker.amazon.common as smac
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    smac.write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(buf, X.astype('float32'), y.astype('float32'))
    buf.seek(0)
    print (buf)
    obj = '{}/{}'.format(prefix, key)
    boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(obj).upload_fileobj(buf)
    print('Wrote dataset: {}/{}'.format(bucket,obj))

writeDatasetToProtobuf(X_train.astype('float32'), y_train.astype('float32'), bucket, train_prefix, train_key)    
writeDatasetToProtobuf(X_test.astype('float32'), y_test.astype('float32'), bucket, test_prefix, test_key)    

print('Output: {}'.format(output_prefix))
```

ValueError: Labels must be a Vector

Comment: could you share the stacktrace as well?

Comment: oh sheesh i havent looked at it forever . it just wasnt working. have they fixed it? aws that is

Comment: there haven't been any changes made to the `write_numpy_to_dense_tensor` function, if that's what you're asking. I was wondering about your stacktrace so that we could see which function calls are leading to the `ValueError`

Comment: i will have to look back in those scripts over the weekend. i think i found a way to overcome this error but then there was another so i kinda stayed away from it. its a known error they need to fix - its not a working product, it only works on their excamples . at least thats how it was 6 months ago

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur if the shapes of y_train and y_test have more than one dimension.

Try something like the following to make your labels a vector:

```
...
y = y.reshape(-1,)
smac.write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(buf, X.astype('float32'), y.astype('float32'))
...
```